# React Navigation Authentication Flow: The action 'NAVIGATE' with payload {"name":"HomeScreen"} was not handled by any navigator

Tags: react-native, aws-amplify, react-navigation-v6

A beginner at React Native here, trying to combine [this doc](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/auth-flow/) with AWS Amplify Authentication to implement React Navigation Authentication Flow but I can't seem to figure out what's wrong. Whenever I click on the login button,  [this error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FYlQ7.png)  appears.

Navigation Code (excluding imports):

```
const NavigationGeneral = () => {

    const [user, setUser] = useState(undefined);

    const checkUser = async () => {
        try {
            const authUser = await Auth.currentAuthenticatedUser({bypassCache: true});
            setUser(authUser);
        } catch (e) {
            setUser(null);
        }
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        checkUser(); 
    }, []);

    if (user === undefined) {
        return (
            <View style = {{flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center'}}>
                <ActivityIndicator />
            </View>
        )
    }

    return (
        <Stack.Navigator screenOptions={{headerShown: false}}>
            {user ? (
                <>
                    <Stack.Screen name = "Login" component = {LoginScreen} />
                    <Stack.Screen name = "SignUp" component = {SignUpScreen} />
                    <Stack.Screen name = "ConfirmEmail" component = {ConfirmEmailScreen} />
                    <Stack.Screen name = "ForgotPassword" component = {ForgotPasswordScreen} />
                    <Stack.Screen name = "NewPassword" component = {NewPasswordScreen} />
                </>
            ): ( 
                <Stack.Screen name = "HomeScreen" component = {HomeTabNavigator} />
            )}
        </Stack.Navigator>
    );
};

//* TAB NAVIGATOR FOR APP SCREENS
const HomeTabNavigator = () => {
    return (
        <Tab.Navigator
            initialRouteName="Home"
            screenOptions={{
                headerShown: false,
                tabBarStyle: {backgroundColor: '#0052cc'},
                tabBarInactiveTintColor: '#fff',
                tabBarActiveTintColor: '#fff',
                tabBarActiveBackgroundColor: '#006600'
            }}>
            <Tab.Screen
                name="Home"
                component={HomeScreen}
                options={{
                tabBarLabel: 'Home',
                tabBarIcon: ({ color, size }) => (
                    <Ionicons name="home-outline" color={'#fff'} size={25} />
                ),
                }}
            />

            <Tab.Screen
                name="Courses"
                component={CourseScreen}
                options={{
                tabBarLabel: 'Courses',
                tabBarIcon: ({ color, size }) => (
                    <Ionicons name="library-outline" color={'#fff'} size={25} />
                ),
                }}
            />

            <Tab.Screen
                name="Profile"
                component={ProfileScreen}
                options={{
                tabBarLabel: 'My Profile',
                tabBarIcon: ({ color, size }) => (
                    <Ionicons name="person-outline" color={'#fff'} size={25} />
                ),
                }}
            />

            <Tab.Screen
                name="Forensic Tools"
                component={ForensicToolsScreen}
                options={{
                tabBarLabel: 'Tools List',
                tabBarIcon: ({ color, size }) => (
                    <Ionicons name="list-outline" color={'#fff'} size={25} />
                ),
                }}
            />

            <Tab.Screen
                name="Leaderboard"
                component={LeaderboardScreen}
                options={{
                tabBarLabel: 'Leaderboard',
                tabBarIcon: ({ color, size }) => (
                    <Ionicons name="podium-outline" color={'#fff'} size={25} />
                ),
                }}
            />

            <Tab.Screen
                name="Settings"
                component={SettingsScreen}
                options={{
                tabBarLabel: 'Settings',
                tabBarIcon: ({ color, size }) => (
                    <Ionicons name="settings-outline" color={'#fff'} size={25} />
                ),
                }}
            />
        </Tab.Navigator>
    );
};

export default NavigationGeneral;
```

`LoginScreen.js` code snippet:

```
const onLoginPressed = async data => {
        if (loading) {
            return;
        }

        setLoading(true);
        try {
            await Auth.signIn(data.username, data.password);
            navigation.navigate("HomeScreen");
            console.log("Login");
        } catch (e) {
            Alert.alert('Oops', e.message);
        }
        setLoading(false);
    };
```

I understand that I'm not supposed to manually navigate using `navigation.navigate()` but rather to conditionally define the screens. But whenever I remove `navigation.navigate("HomeScreen");` from the code, nothing happens when I press the login button. So I assume something is wrong with my conditioning in my `NavigationGeneral` code, I just can't seem to figure out the problem.

Some help or additional tips would be greatly appreciated, thanks in advance. Please let me know if more info is required.

Answer (score 0):

When you try to navigate to the HomeScreen I assume the user is not yet set in the state and therefore the screen with the name HomeScreen does not exist yet, so the navigator has nowhere to go.
Try setting the user in the NavigationGeneral upon login, it should event redirect automatically without using navigation.navigate.

Comment: Sorry but I don't really understand, are you talking about the `checkUser` snippet? If not that one, then which one are you talking about and where do you suggest I relocate it to?  

Answer (score 0):

[You should not trigger navigation manually](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/auth-flow/#dont-manually-navigate-when-conditionally-rendering-screens) when implementing authentication flow with react-navigation. After the successful login, user will be `truthy` value. This means conditional rendering inside of navigation will handle it automatically.

Moreover, in case of condition `user===undefined` do not render LoadingIndicator, instead, create a new loading state and render LoadingIndicator when the state loading becomes true.

And I believe it should be `!user` instead of `user`, since not authenticated user `(user===undefined)` will want to see Login, Signup etc. screens.

```
return (
        <Stack.Navigator screenOptions={{headerShown: false}}>
           // Here it should be !user
            {!user ? (
                <>
                    <Stack.Screen name = "Login" component = {LoginScreen} />
                    <Stack.Screen name = "SignUp" component = {SignUpScreen} />
                    <Stack.Screen name = "ConfirmEmail" component = {ConfirmEmailScreen} />
                    <Stack.Screen name = "ForgotPassword" component = {ForgotPasswordScreen} />
                    <Stack.Screen name = "NewPassword" component = {NewPasswordScreen} />
                </>
            ): ( 
                <Stack.Screen name = "HomeScreen" component = {HomeTabNavigator} />
            )}
        </Stack.Navigator>
    );
```

```
  const [checkAuthUserLoading, setCheckAuthUserLoading] = React.useState(false);
  const user = useSelector((state) => state.user); // Retrieve user from redux store. (It can be mobx, zustand or any other state management.)

  const checkUser = async () => {
    try {
      setCheckAuthUserLoading(true);
      const authUser = await Auth.currentAuthenticatedUser({
        bypassCache: true,
      });
      setCheckAuthUserLoading(false);
      dispatch(setAuthUser(user)); // I would suggest to use state management such as redux or mobx instead of storing user in component state
    } catch (e) {
      dispatch(setAuthUserError(e)); // Here you do not need to setUser(undefined) since its already failed and will be stay as undefined
    }
  };

  if (checkAuthUserLoading) {
    return <LoadingIndicator />;
  }
```

Comment: I think I can understand the code snippet you provided. Can you provide an example of the `user===undefined` section as well? I tried following your suggestions regarding that part but keep running into Render errors.

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate the comments you included, really helpful for a noob like myself. Just to confirm, this `const user = useSelector((state) => state.user);` line of code is incomplete right, or do I just paste it as is? I've never actually used Redux before so I'll have to do some research on it.

Comment: Yes, that was an example of usage how you would use in redux in order to obtain user from redux store